# GIF animate too fast on Computer - iOS

Tags: ios, gif, animated-gif

I am trying to create GIF animated images, for which i pass an array of images.

Lets say I have a 4 seconds video and i extract about 120 frames from it. Regardless of the created GIF size, i create a GIF from all those 120 frames. The problem is, when i open the GIF in iPhone (by attaching it to MailViewComposer or iMessage) it runs fine, but if i email it, or import it to computer, it runs too fast. Can anyone suggest what is wrong here?

I am using [HJImagesToGIF](https://github.com/HarrisonJackson/HJImagesToGIF) for GIF creation. The dictionary for GIF properties is as below:

```
NSDictionary *prep = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.03f]
                                                                                    forKey:(NSString *) kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime]
                                                 forKey:(NSString *) kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];

NSDictionary *fileProperties = @{
                                 (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: @{
                                         (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount: @0, // 0 means loop forever
                                         }
                                 };
```

creation of GIF:

```
CFURLRef url = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

CGImageDestinationRef dst = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeGIF, [images count], nil);
CGImageDestinationSetProperties(dst, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)fileProperties);

for (int i=0;i<[images count];i++)
{
    //load anImage from array
    UIImage * anImage = [images objectAtIndex:i];

    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dst, anImage.CGImage,(__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(prep));

}

bool fileSave = CGImageDestinationFinalize(dst);
CFRelease(dst);
if(fileSave) {
    NSLog(@"animated GIF file created at %@", path);
}else{
    NSLog(@"error: no animated GIF file created at %@", path);
}
```

To save the GIF, I’m using:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tempPath]];
data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:tempPath];

[library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:data metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error Saving GIF to Photo Album: %@", error);
    } else {
        // TODO: success handling
        NSLog(@"GIF Saved to %@", assetURL);
    }
}];
```

Thanks everyone.